# Security risks of file upload-download systems

Tags: c#, security, model-view-controller, file-upload, file-read

I know that there are many posts about these topic. But those posts usually talk about restricting the file types and sizes on so on. Hence non serves to my needs as my system does not have any constraints.

Let's say we have a web application, which accepts uploads from users logged in. These users are authenticated via Active Directory. Anonymous users are not allowed.

Users can upload any type of file to the system. Then users can preview the files uploaded via our multi purpose viewer. Right now we support some basic file types, like pictures, music, video, pdf files and office files. I decide for viewable types by checking a dictionary for viewable types, and if the type don't exist it won't be previewed but downloaded directly.

I am curious about the security risks I have, hence I will try to elaborate my system.

I have two different systems in terms of file keeping procedure:

1. An **internet** application where the storage is a structured file system where file names are changed with guids
2. An **intranet** application where the storage is an unstructured file system where files are directly on the network drive as the user uploaded them, and users can access the files via network drive too

For both applications the previewing strategy is the same.

All files are served from an action method which can only be accessed while authenticated. And logical path traversal for the uploaded files are **allowed**.

The non-office files are returned to the client, and shown in `img`, `video` and `embed` html tags.

On the other hand, the office files are first executed via interop libraries of the Microsoft Office, converted to pdf, then returned to the client, and again showed as a regular pdf.

I am wondering, through these processes am I compromising any security here on the server side? I know that user can upload malicious files, but is there any way user can harm my system upon writing or reading process of the files?

**Update:** I am scanning the file after I've taken it into the temp area by an antivirus. Then if it's ok, committing it into the premamant area.

Comment: From the sound of it, yes - for example if an uploaded malicious MS Office document is processed on the server for viewing.

Comment: I see, then scanning the file upon upload via an antivirus should do the job right?

Comment: Well, it can't hurt, but a new exploit may still get through. You say you're using interop libraries to convert the file on the server? Perhaps you could sandbox that process.

Comment: Yes I use interop libraries. To be precise Office 2010. And actually this process only runs for non-openxml formats(doc, odt, etc.).

Comment: And sandboxing the virus scaning proccess is actually a good idea too. And can you say that there exist no further risks :)

Comment: Well, there are always risks - eg a malicious image file is uploaded and then viewed by another client..